# Bounding $\|A^{-1}\|$ in terms of $\det A$ where $A$ is an integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $d\geq 1$ be an integer. Is there a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (possibly depending on $d$) such that:

1. $f$ tends to $0$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.
2. For every $d\times d$ matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ and a nonzero determinant, we have $\| A^{-1}\|\leq f(|\det(A)|)$.

**Notes**:

1. $\|\cdot\|$ refers to any norm on $M_d(\mathbb{R})$. The particular chosen norm does not matter in the context of this question.
2. The entries of $A^{-1}$ are usually not integral.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this might be the case. The diagonal $2\times 2$ matrix with diagonal entries $1,n$ has determinant $n$ and its inverse has operator norm $1$, so it looks like such an $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: You are correct. I should have thought of what I really want to ask more carefully. I'm sorry for asking a trivial question. I will try again to translate my geometric intuition into a precise question,  more carefully this time.